# Changes to Facelets don't get hot-published

Tags: jsf, facelets, hotdeploy

I'm working on an application that is hosted on a Jboss 5.1 server. If I make an update to the Java code, it immediately gets published on the server on save, but if I edit the Facelets code, the modification doesn't get deployed, no matter what I do. I even tried restarting the server and closing Eclipse, but there seem to be no way to fix that. Any advise would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have automatic builds enabled?

Comment: Hi @nitind, I do have automatic build enabled and also when I do clean all projects the result is the same